# CSS Table cell/row height below 1px?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table, which is some number of columns wide, and is 200 rows tall. I need to style this table so that it is only 200px tall. That is, each row needs to be 1px high. I have tried styling this in CSS, but the table is still showing up too tall. In Chrome, however, it seems to be shrinking like it should, it is only Firefox and Safari (all I have tested it on so far) that it isn't working. Do I need to remove some default styling? Here is the code I have so far:

```
td {
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

tr {
    height: 1px; 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your table's cellspacing 0?

Comment: 1px? what kind of content do the cells contain?

Comment: Well, only certain cells in certain places will have content. Those will then have a rowspan attribute set appropriately.

Comment: you css code invalid

Comment: No problem with your CSS code, but the height of element inside <td></td> can't be more than 1px

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/o120u274/

```
    <table style="border-spacing:0px; width:100%">

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

**style**

```
td{
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

tr {
    height: 1px; 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) td{
    background-color:#AAA;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) td{
    background-color:#A0A;
}
```

I think this may be match with your problem !